# How to carry a banned item on a US flight?

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, hand-luggage, tsa

The [list of banned items](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items) is extensive, but what happens if you have a genuine need to carry something banned? The carry-on specific items is easy enough, you just check it (e.g. sharp objects), but some items (e.g. chlorine, some aerosols, gas torches or many other such objects) which might genuinely be needed for work, are banned in either form.

Is there a process to getting an exemption to carry banned items, and if so, what/where is it?

Comment: If they are banned, they are banned.  If you need something on the list for work or other such use at your end destination, then it will likely need to be shipped by a method other than in your baggage.  Many things banned by TSA are also banned by the FAA which means they can only go by ground means (trucks, trains, surface mail).

Comment: @Tom, surely there are cases where you can apply for an exemption?? A blanket ban seems unusual, even for the TSA.

Comment: How would you justify the need to put passengers on the flight at risk versus shipping it by ground means?  A "last minute need" wouldn't really cut the cake since any sort of government exemption (if even available) takes time to be processed.

Comment: In a majority of cases, it will be easier to buy the banned item at your destination, isn't it?

Comment: For the UK, the first step (and most important step) is to get a license.  Assuming you are interested in sanctioned firearms, the guidance for making an application is here: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/192656/13-805-how-to-apply-for-a-sanctions-derogation-import-licence.pdf  It is rigorous to the extreme.  Once you have a license, there are paths opened for you that lead to transport and logistics.

Comment: @GayotFow - in the US (which Mark specified) firearms are allowed as checked baggage already, no need for an exemption.

Comment: @Tom When I moved from Canada to the UK I shipped my stuff by ocean freight, and I was told that the limits for shipping by ocean were identical to the limits for shipping by air.

Comment: @gerrit - Shipping hazard goods come under all sorts of regulations, depending on what, where and how.

Comment: @Tom Right.  Apparently, that includes matches.

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to answer if we knew what the "banned item" is, and what "genuine need" requires it.  The answer may be very different for a gun in the cabin than for liquids for which there is medical requirement.

Comment: @RichardSmith well, for example, years ago when my family emigrated, we brought a gun with us on the plane. There was a process for it back then with Singapore airlines, to give it to the pilot, be last on, last off etc. Nowadays that isn't possible, but if we were emigrating now...so had a real reason for needing to bring it (moving countries!), whether there is still a process for this, just presumably stricter. (For reference, it was a target pistol)

Comment: @MarkMayo - so is this question specifically about guns?  If so, please update the question to say so.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm keeping it generic for future searches. I would assume there's not a separate process for every single possible banned item, be it guns, medical supplies, gas tanks, whatever - presumably there's a single point of call that one would go through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few exceptions that I know of from the TSA, and these have to do with medication or disability assistance equipment; and children's formula baby food, etc. (for the liquid restriction).

All other prohibitions are not subject to exemptions. This is because some of the items are classified as hazardous material (HAZMAT) that need to carried by certified companies/equipment; in other cases it is banned by the FAA for safety; and finally because it can be considered a weapon.

Your only recourse - if the item cannot be checked in, is to have it shipped to your destination as cargo - and if it is hazmat it may not even be allowed to fly and will have to be driven there.

Comment: Many hazardous material are rejected in ocean containers as well.

Comment: @gerrit they're rejected by most shipping companies because they don't have the equipment, trained staff, and permits to handle them. Contract a company that has those and you can ship them, which will of course be more expensive than taking the cheapest offer and may take longer.

Comment: In some cases, your only recourse may in fact be to purchase it at your destination.